# Showing that ridge regression is a solution to the following optimization problem

Tags: optimization, ridge-regression

$$\hat{\theta}=\arg\min_{\theta}\{ ||y-X\theta||_2^2+\lambda||\theta||_2^2\},$$ where $X$ is an $n\times p$ matrix.

We have if $y=X\theta+\varepsilon$ then $$\hat{\theta}^{\text{ridge}}=(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^Ty$$ So I'm kinda confused, because if $y=X\theta+\varepsilon$, then $||y-X\theta||_2^2+\lambda||\theta||_2^2=||\varepsilon||_2^2+\lambda||\theta||_2^2.$ But I'm confused as to how to show that 
$$(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^Ty=\arg\min_{\theta}\{ ||y-X\theta||_2^2+\lambda||\theta||_2^2\}.$$ Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you. I gotta edit this cause someone said it's a duplicate of an entirely different problem cool.

Comment: Hint: try writing the loss as a function of $\theta$, and then differentiating with respect to $\theta$.

Comment: @jld Sorry, how do I find the loss?

Comment: Loss is another term for the objective function. So the question is what are trying to optimize? It is probably the squared error. So write it down and differentiate and it will lead you to the final equation

Comment: @Drey Yeah, still don't know how to find loss/objective function.

Comment: How do you measure the error of your prediction? That's the loss

Comment: @Drey ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  thats why I'm here buddy

Comment: Hint: look at the first equation in your post.

Comment: @Josh not helping

Comment: @Jeff is this a homework problem?

Comment: @Josh yes, and I don't know how to compute a loss function since we never went over that ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Jeff you don't have to compute it at all; it's provided. It's the thing you're trying to minimize.

Comment: Wish I had known that what was in the argmin was in fact the loss function a;sdljfalskdjfasljdf i hate this class

Comment: Sorry all im definitely being rude or coming off that way but im stupid stressed and trying to decipher what my professor's notes mean is not helping. Thanks all

Comment: How is that the same question @Sycorax, im not finding any coefficients

Comment: @Jeff I'm not sure I understand your comment. Did you read the answer with the most votes? It shows that the two forms in your question are the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think about the problem in summation notation,

The loss is defined, as you said, as $L = \sum_{i=1}^{N}(\sum_{j=1}^{M}\theta_{j}X_{ij} - y_{i})^{2}+ \lambda\sum_{j=1}^{M}\theta_{j}^{2} $

You can differentiate this w.r.t $\theta _{k}$ to find:

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta _{k}} =\sum_{i=1}^{N}2(\sum_{j=1}^{M}\theta_{j}X_{ij}-y_{i})X_{ik} +2\lambda \theta _{k}$

Note that $\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_{ik}\sum_{j=1}^{M}\theta_{j}X_{ij}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_{ik}(X\cdot \theta)_{i}=(X^{T}\cdot X \cdot \theta)_{k}$

and 
$\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_{ik}y_{i}=(X^{T}\cdot y)_{k}$

Putting this together:

$(X^{T}\cdot X\cdot \theta)_{k}-(X^{T}\cdot y)_{k} +\lambda \theta _{k}=0 \hspace{5mm}\forall k$

which you can re-write as a vector equation:

$X^{T}\cdot y= (X^{T}\cdot X + \lambda I)\cdot \theta$

and thus, finally

$\theta = (X^{T}\cdot X + \lambda I)^{-1}\cdot X^{T}\cdot y$

So this has shown that if you assume your loss is given by $||y - X\cdot \theta ||_{2}+\lambda ||\theta||_{2}$ and you wish to find the theta which minimises this loss, then $\theta = (X^{T}\cdot X + \lambda I)^{-1}\cdot X^{T}\cdot y$ is the solution. Hope this answers your question

Comment: Just to clarify, you're condensing $\lambda I$ to just $\lambda$ correct? Thanks for your help

Comment: yes, I didn't explicitly state the presence of the identity matrix, you are correct